# Are there theories or experiments involving multi variable particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, causality, determinism

Every hidden variable/entanglement experiment I’ve ever heard described  involves ONLY one variable of either polarization or spin. Therefore Venn calculations backed by diagrams highlight the limitations or inequalities. Particles with multiple variables are not bound by these limits. Have there been theories proposed that involve polarization and something oscillating or related to frequency?

Comment: This question (v1) seems very broad...

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, there's plenty of them. You haven't heard of them because there's very little to be gained from those frameworks that you can't get from single qubits, so they're confined to the technical literature.

If you're working with a finite number of discrete variables (i.e. anything with a finite number of discrete eigenvalues), then your system has a finite dimension $d$, which is generically bigger than 2, so basically you have a [qudit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit#Variations_of_the_qubit), and the space of observables formed by all the products and combinations of your system's variables is a subset of the set of observables on that qudit. If you want to look for work on Bell inequalities for qudits, try [looking for that on Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=bell+inequality+for+qudits). As of this writing there's some 2,000 results, with the top page providing multiple relevant examples.

If you want to work with variables that can take a continuous range of values, such as momentum and position, then there is a complete sub-field known as [continuous-variable quantum information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-variable_quantum_information). If you want to look specifically for Bell-type inequalities there, try [the obvious Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=bell+inequality+for+continuous+variables), which produces a slew of relevant results.

Comment: Your overthinking what I'm saying. Particles with extra variables can show correlations matching QM or cos2theta. A bi-variable could be both polarization and a rotating cycle. Picture a knife rotating vertically as it moves along to the target. Of course the vertical polarization plays an important roll but the rotation does too. Place a vertical slot along the way and the knife has no problem. Place a horizontal slot and it's stopped. Rotate the slot to some angle in between and the knife may make it depending on where the rotation is when it it gets to the slot. It can match cos2theta.

Comment: Because of the bi-variable which Bell did not consider the results will match QM exactly.

Comment: @BillAlsept If this is going to be a bait-and-switch game then I'm not playing. I have answered the question as you've posed it. Since you seem uninterested in the answer, I'm uninterested in continuing this conversation.

Comment: It's no bait and switch. I feel you have not truly considered what I'm saying or I'm still not articulating it. What you said about the extra variables confirms that. Bell said No theory could match QM predictions and I just showed you a simple and crude example. Thanks for your time